# Can you still lock rows exclusively (block readers) in a SQL Server db that has Snapshot Isolation and RCSI enabled?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, snapshot-isolation, read-committed-snapshot

Can you still lock rows exclusively (block readers) in a SQL Server db that has Snapshot Isolation and RCSI enabled?

I want to basically do a xlock, rowlock select on a table.

Comment: No. And the whole point of this question is to possibly avoid that, since trying it is not just a matter of running the command, but also setting up a rather complicated test to see if it works.

Comment: I guess we'll have to disagree on what "rather complicated" means.

Comment: Take a chill pill, man. We can't all be as great as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can lock rows exclusively (either using DML or locking hints). But readers also using snapshot isolation will not be blocked because they don't take locks (on data).

After all, not locking and blocking is a prime advantage of snapshot isolation.